# What is the time complexity of K-fold cross-validation?

Tags: cross-validation

What is the time complexity of $K$-fold cross-validation? (linear in $K$, quadratic in $K$, cubic in $K$, exponential in $K$?)

My guess is linear in $K$, because each fold is evaluated once? $\mathcal{O}(K)$? (no pun intended).

Comment: I would say practically you are mostly likely going to use CV to search for the best hyperparameters of a mdelling algorithm. In that case I would say the complexity is $O(K * O(ModelAlgorithm(n)) * hp)$ where hp is the number of hyper-parameters you are searching over. If you ignore the modelling and the hyper parameter search, I agree that it would be linear in K.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's $O(n)$, where $n$ is your sample size, since you are going through your data $K$ times $O(Kn)$, but $K$ is just a constant. Each iteration you use $K-1$ folds for training and then you use the remaining fold to evaluate your model. So you are reading your whole data $K$ times.

But this is just for CV, not accounting for the models built on top of the folds.

If $K$ approaches $n$ (LOOCV) then the time complexity is actually $O(n^2)$.

Comment: You cannot say $\mathcal{O}(n)$, because you don't know how the complexity of the fitting algorithm itself.

Comment: @Curious I agree that the question is ill defined because CV is not an algorithm in itself but rather a method to evaluate models - around actual algorithms, so we cannot really talk about CV time complexity. However, if we indulge in some assumptions and say that we are fitting a very simple model such as one that always returns the mean (of one variable) of the training folds, then such a calculation holds, because that takes $O(n)$ time.

Answer (score 1):

- The usual and most general formulation of cross validation is embarassingly parallel. Computational time is *approximately* $k$ times the time to train the model on the whole data set.

  The time to train any such surrogate model may be sensitive to

  - the numeber of cases actually in training ($\frac{k-1}{k}$th of the available cases)
  - predicting the remaining $\frac{1}{k}$th of the cases
  - the range of hyperparameters to consider.

  The time complexity of these factors dependends entirely on the model that is undergoing the cross validation: Consider e.g. the hyperparameter grid. For certain models updating with a different hyperparameter set may be done in a fashion that saves large parts of the computation. E.g. in Principal Component Regression,  the time consuming step is typically the SVD ($O (n^3)$). Calculating results for varying numbers of retained components from one SVD is possible and often much faster than recalculating the SVD every time. Also this particular re-use of intermediate results is unproblematic in the sense that it doesn't introduce any particular risk of causing a data leak between testing and training.

---

- For the special case of $k = n$, i.e. leave-one-out cross validation and particular training algorithms, analytical expressions to calculate the LOO estimate are known. In that case, a whole lot of calculation may be saved.
- For further algorithms it may be possible to formulate model updates that calculate the effect of exchanging $\frac{1}{k-1}$ of the training cases and predicting them, also saving calculations.

The latter 2 approaches can IMHO be interesting when cross validation is employed during model training (e.g. for hyperparameter optimization).

For verifcation/validation purposes on the other hand they are less useful as not only a "theoretical" performance is to be tested but the actual implementation of the training algorithm. Which means that the described calculational shortcuts should be avoided, the more so a logical error here may cause a data leak between training and test data.